# In SymPy, how to calculate posterior probability?

Tags: statistics, probability, sympy

Assuming that I have defined 2 probability variables in SymPy:

```
x = Normal('x', 0, 2)
y = 2*x + Normal('0', 3)
```

Now given evidence that y = 4, is it possible to define a new probability variable that follow the posterior distribution P(x | y=4)?

It is easy to simply multiply the probability distribution function of 2, however I wonder whether sympy has the feature to yield a probability variable directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way is to pass conditions as the second argument without creating a new random symbol: for example,

```
density(x, Eq(y, 4))    # Lambda(x, 5*sqrt(2)*exp(8/25)*exp(-x**2/8)*exp(-2*(-x + 2)**2/9)/(12*sqrt(pi)))
P(x > 0, Eq(y, 4))      # -erfc(8*sqrt(2)/15)/2 + 1
```

But it's also possible to create a random variable with a custom density using [ContinuousRV](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/stats.html#sympy.stats.ContinuousRV):

```
from sympy.stats import ContinuousRV
x_post = Symbol("x_post")
X_post = ContinuousRV(x_post, density(x, Eq(y, 4))(x_post))
```

For example, `simplify(E(X_post))` returns `16*erf(3*sqrt(2)/10)/25 + 16*erfc(3*sqrt(2)/10)/25 + 16/25`.

Comment: Marked as solved as the non-stopping solving of 'variance' is likely caused by a bug in the library